# WireMock json stub not adding the request body to response body in a post request

Tags: spring-boot, docker-compose, http-post, wiremock

I am trying to print the contents of the request body that I receive as a JSON object using the following code:

```
{
  "request": {
    "method": "POST",
    "urlPath": "/endpoint"
  },
  "response": {
    "status": 200,
    "body": "{\"request\": {{{request.body}}}, \"anotherField\": \"string\" }",
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
    },
    "transformers": ["response-template"]
  }
}
```

Here is the response json I get:

```
{
    "request": {
        {request.body
        }
    },
    "anotherField": "string"
}
```

I have tried using the $ and @ symbols with the response body not is not working

Comment: Have you enabled `--global-response-templating` or `--local-response-templating` when starting WireMock? I ran your example mapping and was able to receive the `request.body` in my response, and I'm starting my WireMock with `--global-response-templating`.

Comment: @SternK thank you for your response. How can i enable --global-response-templating?